i am trying to delete and reinstall the automation anywhere bot agent
When I click on Connect to my local device in Automation Anywhere Community Edition control room the setup of the bot agent gets downloaded, but when I click on that setup to install it nothing is happening.
I used it at least 3 months ago but after that I deleted it and when I want to use it again I am unable to do so. Please help me to reinstall the bot agent
I check in the "Services" app of Windows and Control Panel, Automation Anywhere is not listed anywhere. And when I click on it other setups present in my computer like visual studio.exe, chromeSetup.exe start getting installed but not so for bot agents. I think it is my system problem because in my friends computer it is working well.

Can you add more details on what error are you getting or any screenshots if you have?
